# Why does my layout cause my app to crash?

Tags: android, android-layout

And what are the rules I need to keep in order to avoid a layout crash?

For example, I have this layout with just 4 Buttons and 4 TextView.
I really don't know why it causes crash on some devices and on other devices it works ok.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ConnectButton"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/Connect" >
    </Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/DisconnectButton"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/Disconnect" >
    </Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/NoAlertButton"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/NoAlert" >
    </Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/MildAlertButton"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/MildAlert" >
    </Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/HighAlertButton"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/HighAlert" >
    </Button>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/AlertLevelSelectionLabel"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/SelectAlertLevel" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/CurrentRSSILevelLabel"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/CurrentRSSILevel" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ConnectedToLabel"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/ConnectToLabel" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ImmediateAlert"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ffff3333"
        android:text="@string/ImmediateAlert"
        android:textSize="42sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" >
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

The crash appears only after clicking the button, so it may be related to the TextViews that appear after them, but I don't know why the TextViews cause the layout crash.
I assume it is a layout issue since the horizontal layout of the same application works OK.

Comment: can you show your logcat detail?

Comment: I will guess that your `portrait` and `landscape` layout have different _ids_ for some of the elements, hence the crash...

Comment: pls make sure that your button ID is valid(from the the set layout)!!

Comment: K-ballo is right .. do you have different layout for land and port?

Comment: The Buttons ID are the same. and they are all as written in the code above so i guess they are valid names, since it works for horizontal.

Comment: I even tried to erase the layout-port, and work only with 1 layout directory. but it still doesnt work.

Comment: what secret is there in your logcat?

Comment: hey did you get your issue resloved?

Comment: i cant attach the logcat, since i dont know how. if you can share the layout rules i need to stick in order to avoid layout crash please let me know.

Comment: your layout is fine at first look...(In eclipse) to open logcat open DDMS-select logcat explorer- select E tag then Ctrl+c and ctrl+v..

Comment: @Yaniv where you placed your string file?